# C: speed up for permutation of bits from given permutation table; searching for the minimum

Tags: c, performance, permutation

I'm searching for a fast permutation of bits within a number in C.

I have an integer value and table of permutation positions. Not all possible permutations are listet, just n!*2<sup>n</sup> of the 2<sup>n</sup>! possible permutations.
For simplicity I will show the data as 4-Bit numbers (`n=2`, `lutsize = 8`), in reality they are 32-Bit numbers (`n=5`, `lutsize=3840`):

```
static const uint8_t lut[lutsize][4] = {
{0, 1, 2, 3},
{1, 0, 3, 2},
{2, 3, 0, 1},
{3, 2, 1, 0},
{0, 2, 1, 3},
{1, 3, 0, 2},
{2, 0, 3, 1},
{3, 1, 2, 0}};
```

So the first entry is the identity, for the second entry the bits 1&2 and 2&3 switch places and so on. I wrote a method which calculates the values and returns the minimal value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

enum { n = 2 };
enum { expn = 1<<n };

enum { lutsize = 8 };
static const uint8_t lut[lutsize][4] = {
    {0, 1, 2, 3},
    {1, 0, 3, 2},
    {2, 3, 0, 1},
    {3, 2, 1, 0},
    {0, 2, 1, 3},
    {1, 3, 0, 2},
    {2, 0, 3, 1},
    {3, 1, 2, 0}
};

uint32_t getMin(uint32_t in, uint32_t* ptr){
    uint32_t pos, i, tmp, min;
    uint8_t bits[expn];
    
    tmp = in;
    for (i = 0; i < expn; ++i){ // extract bits into array
        bits[i] = tmp & 1;
        tmp = tmp >> 1;
    }
    min = in;
    for (pos = 0; pos < lutsize; ++pos){ // for each row in the permutation table
        tmp = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < expn; ++i){ // for each bit
            tmp = tmp | (bits[i] << lut[pos][i]);  // put bit i on position lut[pos][i]
        }
        ptr[pos] = tmp; // store result (optional)
        //printf("%d: %d\n", pos, tmp);
        if (tmp<min) { min = tmp; }  // track minimum       
    }
    //printf("min: %d\n", min);
    return min;
}

void main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    uint32_t ptr[lutsize];
    printf("%u\n", (unsigned)getMin(5, ptr));
    assert(getMin(5, ptr) == 3);
    assert(getMin(0b0110, ptr) == 6);
}
```

gives the output for the example number `5` if you uncomment the `printf`'s:

```
0: 5
1: 10
2: 5
3: 10
4: 3
5: 3
6: 12
7: 12
min: 3
```

I do calculate each permutation in a naive way by separating the bits into an array and then pushing them into their new position. I write the results into an array and keep track of the minimum which is returned at the end.

**How do improve the performance of the procedure `getMin` for `n=5`?**
I'm primarily interested in the minimum.

Additional input:

- the permutation table can be read as "bit value comes from position" or "bit value shifts to position". The results are the same, just the order of the entries differs.
- it is not necessary (but a bonus) to use the array (`ptr`)
- the goal is to reduce the time to compute the smallest bit permutation number for all 32-bit numbers in random order. Precalculating all possible minimum numbers is ok. Using multiple versions of the lut is ok. Anything is ok as long it does not take more than 4GB of ram like storing all possible input/output pairs would do.
- sorry for the not so c-like code. I'm out of training.

Here is the python code to generate the look up table for `n=5`:

```
from itertools import permutations 
import numpy as np
import math

for n in [5]:
    expn = 1<<n #2:4 3:8; 4:16; 5:32
    order = np.zeros((int(math.factorial(n))*expn, expn), dtype=np.int8) # n!*2^n x 2^n matrix
    cnt = 0 # current entry
    permneg = np.zeros(expn, dtype=int)
    for perm in permutations(list(range(n))): #shuffle order
        ini = np.array(list(range(expn)), dtype=int) # list 0 to expn-1
        out = np.zeros(expn, dtype=int)
        for i in range(n): # apply permutation on position level
            tmp = ini & 1 # get value on least bit
            out += tmp << perm[i] #put it on the right postion
            ini = ini >> 1 # next bit as least bit
        for neg in range(expn): # include 0/1 swaps (negation)
            for i in range(len(out)): # for all 2^n negation cases
                permneg[i] = out[i] ^ neg # negate on negation bits
            order[cnt]=permneg # store
            cnt += 1 # increase counter
            
    print("enum { lutsize = "+str(len(order))+" };")
    s='},\n{'.join(', '.join(map(str,sl)) for sl in order)
    print("static const uint8_t lut[lutsize]["+str(expn)+"] = {\n{"+s+"}\n};")
```

Comment: Are you searching for faster method to generate all permutations of bits or for faster method for finding the minimum value of all bit permutations? The tasks are really unrelated. If you want the minimum, just count the number of set bits with some bit twiddling hack, and then create a number with that many bits set.

Comment: I'm searching for the minimum value. Since not all possible permutations are in the list, just counting the bits is not enough.

Comment: So given, ex. `0b10101010` the minimum is `0b1111`? Ie. the minimum is a number with the same count of bits set as the input number, right? Would you be able to give some more examples of inputs&outputs, like numbers and minimum,  so others can unit-test their code?

Comment: yes, the output of `0b10101010` (170) would be `0b1111` (15), but the output of `0b0110` (6) would be still `0b0110` (6)

Comment: Note that your code as it is now will not compile - could you add `#include`s and change constants to `enum { ... }` so they are constant expressions? `the output of 0b0110 (6) would be still 0b0110 (6)` whoa!... why not `0b11`?

Comment: because there is no such permutation in the list. for n=2 there are (2^n)!=4*3*2*1=24 possible permutations, yet just 8 are listed in the look up table.

Comment: @KamilCuk could you give me an example website for the enum part? I'm a bit confused where and how to use them. For n? Or for expn? For lut? Or could you just edit your suggestions into the code?

Comment: [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/e5Ge4a).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two optimizations : 1) store the value of the set bit in the table instead. 2) Don't store each bit in an array but compute it on the fly instead. The result is the same, but it's probably a little bit faster.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define lutsize 8

static const uint8_t lutn[lutsize][4] = {
    {1, 2, 4, 8},
    {2, 1, 8, 4},
    {4, 8, 1, 2},
    {8, 4, 2, 1},
    {1, 4, 2, 8},
    {2, 8, 1, 4},
    {4, 1, 8, 2},
    {8, 2, 4, 1}};    

uint32_t getMin(uint32_t in, uint32_t* ptr)
{
    uint32_t pos, i, tmp, min;
    uint8_t bits[expn];
    tmp = in;
    min = in;
    for (pos = 0; pos < lutsize; ++pos){ 
        tmp = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < expn; ++i) {
            // If the bit is set
            if (in & (1<<i)) 
                // get the value of the permuted bit in the table
                tmp = tmp | lutn[pos][i];
        }
        ptr[pos] = tmp;
        //printf("%d: %d\n", pos, tmp);
        if (tmp<min) { min = tmp; }  // track minimum       
    }
    //printf("min: %d\n", min);
    return min;
}

void main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    uint32_t *ptr;
    
    ptr = (uint32_t*) malloc(lutsize * sizeof(uint32_t));
    getMin(5, ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that, not having all the possible permutations, you need to check all of those you have. Calculating the best permutation is not fruitful if you aren't sure that permutation is available.

So, the two optimizations remaining you can hope for are:

1. Stop the search if you achieve a minimum.

For example, if I have understood, you have the binary number 11001101. What is the minimum permutation value? Obviously 00011111, with all ones to the right. What exact permutation does this for you - whether the last 1 is the first, second, fifth, sixth or eight bit - matters not to you.

As soon as a permutation hits the magic value, that is the minimum and you know you can do no better, so you can just as well stop searching.

In your own example you hit the minimum value 3 (or 0011, which is the minimum from 1001 or 5) at iteration 4. You gained nothing from iterations five to seven.

2. If you have 1101, Go from { 0, 1, 3, 2 } to the bit-permutated value "1110" as fast as possible.

Not sure about the performances, but you could try precalculating the values from the table, even if this requires a 32x32 = 1024 32-value table - 4M of memory.

Considering the first position (our number is 1101), the permutation can have in position 0 only these values: 0, 1, 2, or 3. These have a value of 1___, 1___, 0___ or 1___. So our position 0 table is { 1000, 1000, 0000, 1000 }.
The second position is identical: { *1*_, *1*_, *0*_, *1*_ } and so we have { 0100, 0100, 0000, 0100 }.
The next two rows are { 0010, 0010, 0000, 0010 }
{ 0001, 0001, 0000, 0001 }.

Now, you want to calculate the value if permutation { 3, 0, 1, 2 } is applied:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    value |= table[i][permutation[i]];
}
```

===

But (again, *if* I understood the problem), let us say that the number has one fourth zeroes (it is made up of 24 1's, 8 0's) and the table is sizeable enough.

There is a very significant chance that you very soon hit both a permutation that puts a bit 1 in the 31st position, yielding some 2 billion, and another that puts a 0 there, yielding one billion.

The minimum will then surely be below two billions, so from now on, as soon as you check the first permutated bit and find it is a 1, you can stop calculating, you won't get a better minimum out of that permutation. Skip immediately to the next.

If you do this check at every cycle instead of only the first,

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    value |= table[i][permutation[i]];
    if (value > minimum) {
        break;
    }
}
```

I fear that you might eat any gains, but on the other hand, since values are automatically ordered in descending order, the first bits would get eliminated the most, avoiding the subsequent checks. It might be worth checking.

Nothing stops you from doing the calculation in two steps:

```
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    value |= table[i][permutation[i]];
    if (value > minimum) {
        break;
    }
}
if (value < minimum) {
    for (; i < 32; i++) {
        value |= table[i][permutation[i]];
    }
}
```